# When is the ratio of Jacobi theta functions algebraic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences

Probably this is well known.

$\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$ are Jacobi theta functions
as defined in [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) (31) and (32).

For natural $n$ define
$$ f(n) = \frac{\theta_2(-e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}})}{\theta_3(-e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}))}$$

According to mathworld (46), $f(3)$ is algebraic.

Experimentally $f(n)$ is algebraic at least for

$$ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 15 , 16 , 18 , 19 , 22 , 23 , 25 , 27 , 28 , 31 , 37 , 39 , 43 , 55 , 58 , 63 , 67 , 163$$

This holds to precision $10^4$ and the list might be incomplete.

The sequence doesn't appear in OEIS though includes
all [Heegner numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number).

> Q1 When is $f(n)$ algebraic?
>
> Q2 Why Heegner numbers are in the list?
>
> Q3 Is there closed form for some other $f(n)$?.
>
> Q4 Is $f(n)$ algebraic for other $n$?

Comment: $f(n)$ is essentially the "lambda function" (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html) or the "elliptic modulus", and I think the indices correspond (maybe not 1-to-1) to "elliptic integral singular values" (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html)

Comment: @FredrikJohansson Thank you :-). Why not 1-to-1?

Comment: They're all algebraic, by the theory of complex multiplication.  For example, for $\ n=14$ (the first number not in your list) I find that $2f(n)^4$ is a root of
$$ x^8 - 8x^7 - 1964x^6 + 11896x^5 - 27034x^4 + 28680x^3 - 14764x^2 + 3976x + 1. $$
Values at "Heegner numbers" are easiest to recognize because the degree is small.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies is the degree of $f(n)^4$ bounded (possibly conjecturally) infinitely often?

Comment: On the contrary, it's known that the degree tends to $\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, because it's within a bounded factor of the class number of ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-n}\,)$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks, but $n$ need not be squarefree and might be square leading to infinitely many isomorphic number fields.

Comment: Good point; 
I should have described the dependence on $n$ a bit more carefully:
The degree is within a constant factor of the class number of the
*order* ${\bf Z}[\sqrt{-n}\,]$.  This does increase with $\;n$,
even in a family such as $n = m^2 n_0$.